# How to add an environmental variable in the terminal in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm currently learning Django through 'real python' website and in the tutorial it asks to add an environmental variable in the terminal like this,

```
(venv) $ export EMAIL_HOST_USER=your_email_host_user
```

(for Linus or macOS)

```
C:\> set EMAIL_HOST_USER=your_email_host_user
```

(for Windows)

but I'm using PyCharm to code these and these doesn't work in the terminal that PyCharm provides.
How do I add environmental variables in PyCharm?

This is the link to what I'm learning to do https://realpython.com/django-user-management/#send-emails-to-the-outside-world

Comment: Go  to edit configurations under "run" and there is an edit box for env variables

Comment: @flakes Thanks! After I add them where are they located? I'm trying to get them but not sure the location... In the example above they called it like this  os.environ.get("EMAIL_HOST_USER")

Comment: Env variables are available when the program is launched. You can see all of your env variables from python by running `import os; print(os.environ)`

Comment: Might want to read up on them https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable . Env vars are a lightweight way to configure applications/ processes on your computer. There are a number of standard variables like `PATH` which tells processes where to look for exectuables, and many other use cases. Every app can define whatever variables they want, or expect variables with custom names to be set (like what is being expected by your example).

Comment: @flakes thank you! that helped lots! I still get lots of error but at least I got this part done

Comment: For Linux, one option is you can add environment variables in terminal as suggested and then launch pycharm from terminal itself. All the environment variables would reflect in pycharm too.

Comment: Yes,  on osx for example, I put my common env variables in my `.bash_profile`, and pycharm will pick up on those. For windows, there is a view in the control panel that lets you set environment variables globally for all applications,

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
Run/Debug Configuration
  -> Edit configurations ... 
  -> Environment variables
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. What application are you using to make this video?

Comment: `ScreenFlow` - it provides direct exports to animated `GIF`s. If you plan to use the tool on `macOS` and on `Windows`, I'd suggest to go with `Camtasia` - it is double licensed (you can use it on both systems).

Answer (score 0):

Either go  to "Run" or the dropdown and select "Edit Configurations..":

[image]

For your runtime  configuration, select "Environment Variables":

[image]

Add as many environment variables as you need:

[image]